# Sort Text Column in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I apply the `mat-sort-header` to the `mat-text-column` component for angular material tables?

Standard way:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <mat-text-column mat-sort-header name="name"></mat-text-column>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Or is there any other way how I can achieve sortable `mat-text-column` components?